# How to override tabbar's more controller?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I'm having very annoying problem with UITabBarController's "more" tab controller. It supports rotation to landscape mode by default, but does not propagate the event to it's subviews (or view controllers which are managed by it) by calling appropriate delegate methods, so all controllers under the "more" section can be rotated, which is not what I want - I need just one of them to support autorotation.

The issue is that I cannot find how to override and use custom class for the more tab controller.

Does anybody know how to override more tab controller or make it somehow to call delegate method's on subviews?

thanks much for any tip

Answer (score 1):

Since the more controller is a private class, there is no public SDK way to do this. The easiest way to solve this would be to re-implement the more controller manually (it's just a very simple `UITableViewController`)